# appendix, localization issue

Tags: appendices

The command

```
\appendixpage
```

print

```
Appendices
```

I would like it to print

```
Apêndice
```

Yes, in Brazilian Portuguese. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The `appendix`package gives you  the tools for that:

```
\documentclass[brazilian]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %
\usepackage{babel} %
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Apêndice}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Apêndice}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\appendix \appendixpage \noappendicestocpagenum \addappheadtotoc

\chapter{Some title} Some text

\end{document}
```